# Use excel sheet as a template and quickly switch to other input values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a sheet that takes 10 input parameters and a whole bunch of caluculations.

Now I would like Excel to do the calculations on another array of input parameters, *without having to copy the sheet*.

Actually, I would like to be able to *easily switch between different arrays of input parameters*.  Ideally, I can store these input parameters for all scenarios on a different sheet, and then select the desired on in the main sheet using a drop box.

Can somebody point me into the right direction?  Does anybody know about an example for this?

Thank you!
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is fine for me.
You can set up a table in an empty sheet where first column lists parameter meaningful names, and each one of the successive columns contains a different parameter value set.
Then, on the "bunch calculation" sheet you set up a unique cell to choose a column of the table in the other sheet, and in the cells containing parameters you have to define a formula that using INDEX function retrieves the right value from the parameters table.
So, changing the value of only one cell you realize istantly a whole different calculation without having to select a different sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `INDIRECT()` function.

Sheet1

```
Input1  111
Input2  222
```

Sheet2

```
Input1  42
Input2  43
```

Sheet3

```
Sheet1
=INDIRECT(A1&"!"&"A1")+INDIRECT(A1&"!"&"A2")
```

Now `Sheet3!A2` displays "333". If you change `Sheet3!A1` to "Sheet2", then `Sheet3!A2` will display "85". You can simplify your calculation formulas by not mixing in a whole bunch of `INDIRECT()` functions if you isolate them to an area on Sheet3 (or even its own sheet) and have your formulas only do their normal thing but referencing this intermediate area.